# Different form formatter for embeded form?

Tags: php, forms, symfony1

I'm trying to change the form formatter of the embeded form. Is it possible to approach something like this?

```
class sfOuterForm extends sfForm {
  public function configure()
  {
    $innerForm = new sfForm();
    $this->embedForm('inner', $innerForm);
    $this->getWidgetSchema()->setFormFormatter('list');
    $this->getEmbeddedForm('inner')->getWidgetSchema()->setFormFormatterName('table');
  }
}
```

i'm expecting the following:

```
echo (new sfOuterForm())
```

outputs:

```
<li><label>Outer Label</label><input type="text" /></li>
<li>
  <table>
   <tr><td><label>Inner Label</label></td><td><input type="text" /></td></tr>
  </table>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Once a form is embedded, it's original widget schema and validator schema do nothing - they've been merged into the top level schemas. Thus, you need to set the form formatter before embedding:

```
$this->getWidgetSchema()->setFormFormatter('list');
$innerForm = new sfForm();
$innerForm->getWidgetSchema()->setFormFormatterName('table');
$this->embedForm('inner', $innerForm);
```

It's worth a look into sfForm::embedForm to see what's going on internally.

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer my question by myself :)
The problem arised when i tried to change formatter for relation's embedded forms. I solved this as follows:

```
class sfOuterForm extends sfForm {
  public function configure()
  {
    $innerForm = new sfForm();
    $this->embedRelation('relationName');
    $this->getWidgetSchema()->setFormFormatter('list');
    $this->getEmbeddedForm('relationName')->getWidgetSchema()->setDefaultFormFormatterName('table');
  }
}
```

Hope this will help someone :)

Comment: Thanks! I tried "setFormFormatterName" for embedded forms, but only "setDefaultFormFormatterName" works.